# さくらのvps for windows serverでポート開放ができない

Tags: windows-server

さくらのvpsでゲームのサーバーを立てたいのですが、ファイアーウォールの設定で受信、送信ともに必要なポートの接続を許可してもListen状態になりません。
windows serverのプランでは無理なのでしょうか？
また現在お試し期間中なのですが、それも何か関係しているのでしょうか？

追記：ポート開放ツールなども使用しましたが、いずれも失敗しています。

Comment: 参考 [パケットフィルター](https://manual.sakura.ad.jp/vps/network/packetfilter.html)

Comment: パケットフィルターはfor windows server のプランでは利用できないとのことです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ポートがListen状態になっていないということは

- サーバとなるプログラムが起動していない
- ポートを見誤っている

ということです。ファイヤーウォールの設定は関係ありません。

Comment: 今見てみたところTCPではなくUDPの方のポートを使っていたようで、そっちをファイアーウォールでちゃんと設定してあげると出来ました！
プログラムが使ってないならそりゃlisten状態にもなりませんよね・・・
回答ありがとうございました！